# Adding multiple variables to sweetalert content object

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I am aware that it is possible to add HTML elements to the sweetalert alert box by using the `content` object. 
For example:

```
var link1 = document.createElement('a');
link1.innerHTML = 'How do I logout?';
swal({
    title: 'FAQ',
    content: link1
});
```

However, I was wondering if it was possible to add multiple variables to the content object e.g.

```
var link1 = document.createElement('a');
var link2 = document.createElement('a');
link1.innerHTML = 'How do I logout?';
link2.innerHTML = "How do I example?";
swal({
    title: 'FAQ',
    content: link1 + '\n' + link2 //NOTE: this doen't work but I hope this demostrates what I am asking
});
```

I want to do this so that I can create links which open different sweetalert alert boxes depending on which link is clicked.

Version of sweetalert:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Try replacing `\n` with `<br>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. `link1 + link2` does not display anything either.

Comment: Oh, of course. I thought `link1` and `link2` were strings. My bad. I think I have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try crating a `<div>`, adding the elements into it and then passing the `<div>` to SweetAlert.

```js
const link1 = document.createElement('a');
const link2 = document.createElement('a');
link1.innerHTML = 'How do I logout?';
link2.innerHTML = "How do I example?";

const container = document.createElement("div");
// You could also use container.innerHTML to set the content.
container.append(link1);
container.append(document.createElement("br"));
container.append(link2);

swal({
    title: 'FAQ',
    content: container
});
```